# Element of array not reflect inside Option tag in React JSX

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing the front end used by React JSX and I don't understand why the object elements are not displayed inside the Option tag from the element of the Select form:

```
<FormGroup className="col-md-5 mb-3">
   <Label for="type">Astronomer Name</Label>
   <select className="custom-select" name="astronomer_name" id="astronomer_name" onChange={this.handleChange} >
   <option selected type="text" autoComplete="astronomer_name">{item.astronomer_name || ''}</option>
   {Object.keys(astronomers).map((astronomer, index) => {
   return <option key={index} value={index}>{astronomer.astronomer_name}</option>})}
  </select>
</FormGroup>
```

And I got empty lines inside this tag by the number of elements in the object (HTML code):

```
<option type="text" autocomplete="astronomer_name">astronomer 2</option>
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="1"></option>
<option value="2"></option>
<option value="3"></option>
<option value="4"></option>
```

The same code using a variable gives objects like [objectObject] (HTML code):

```
<option type="text" autocomplete="astronomer_name">astronomer 2</option>
<option value="0">[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]</option>
<option value="1">[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]</option>
<option value="2">[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]</option>
...
```

Outside of the tags, this code gives the desired result:

```
<p>{tempAstronomers}</p>
```

and I got (HTML code):

```
<p>
  <p>astronomer 1</p>
  <p>astronomer 2</p>
  <p>astronomer 3</p>
...
</p>
```

Comment: Can you add value of astronomers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys` returns the keys of an object as an array. If you store your astronomers in an object, use `Object.values(astronomers)` to retrieve the names. If you store the astronomers in an array, use `astronomers.map`.